# Entity Framework/MVC3: temporarily disable validation

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am using EF Code First. I heavily use code annotations to specify how the data (model) should be validated. However, often I just need validation at UI layer and be able to suppress validation when I save certain data to the database in the code. However, once I specified validation rules, they are applied everywhere -- on the UI, on the database, on the data access layer.

Can I temporarily disable model validation at EF layer so I can save the data using `SaveChanges()` without getting validation exceptions?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You just need to set `Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false` in your context class before calling `SaveChanges()`.

```
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I wish I had found this weeks ago. Great for bulk imports.

Comment: This is so helpful! It works with MVC 4 and EF 6 too. I have a SQL Server DB full of data converted from a Lotus Notes DB. I needed a way to have the application let the user set the status column to "Archived" or "Deleted" without forcing them to correct the data first (they aren't going to use the row any more anyway). Setting ValidateOnSaveEnabled to false before doing .SaveChanges() worked perfectly for me!

Comment: Is there a way to have a non-nullable fields generated as null thus allowing temporary saving of non-validated null fields?