# Entity validation in foreach loop, if validation fails it stays failed for next loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, model

I'm having a strange issue. I have a database with existing items, I added a new validation rule so some of the items in the database don't comply with this new rule.

I have a loop that finds a record, changes an element then saves it back to the database, like this:

```
foreach(int foo in bar)
{
    Model model = db.Model.Find(foo);
    model.updated = true;
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I figured that for records that don't comply to the new validation rule would just not be updated because the `ModelState.IsValid` wouldn't pass. This is not the case though, it trows a validation failed exception. So I put it in a `try catch` and figured while I'm at it I'll log the error so I know what records arn't valid. So it now looks like this:

```
foreach(int foo in bar)
{
    Model model = db.Model.Find(foo);
    model.updated = true;
    try
    {
        db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception x)
    {
        // log error
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ErrorLogs.Add(errorLog);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

This also trows a validation failed exception, i guess because the exception in the `try` is not cleared. So fine, I decide to just try, and not catch the error. So it looks like this:

```
foreach(int foo in bar)
{
    Model model = db.Model.Find(foo);
    model.updated = true;
    try
    {
        db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch()
    {
    }
}
```

Now what ends up happening is that say I have 100 records that are cycled through the foreach loop, if #27 fails validation every record that comes after fails and therefore is not updated!

This is very aggravating, how can I fix this? Is there a way to clear the validation error? Why is the error persisting to all the other loops? Is it because `db` was declared outside the loop? <s>And why is it passing the ModelState.IsValid in the first place?</s>

Thanks

Comment: have you check with `for` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confusing ASP.NET MVC validation with Entity Framework's validation.

- `ModelState.IsValid` checks the validity of the models that were bound to your MVC Action's parameters.
- Entity Framework does its own validation of the entities that it tries to save.

It appears that the aspects of your model which aren't valid are not those which were sent to your action method, but rather those which came out of the database. So when the model binding occurred, you had a valid object, and `ModelState.IsValid` is true. But when you try to save the objects, Entity Framework still detects that they are invalid and throws an exception.

It seems odd that you would create validation on your entities that causes current data in the database to be incorrect. Consider running a SQL script to correct the data in the database.

If you can't do that, you could try binding the entities after having loaded them out of the database:

```
var models = db.Model.Where(f => bar.Contains(f.Id)).ToList();
TryUpdateModel(models);
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
    foreach(var model in models)
    {
        model.updated = true;
        db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Of course, the above code only works if *all* of the model are valid. If you want to selectively update only the correct ones, you could check the `ModelState.Errors` property for errors pertaining to each model entry.

If you really want to suppress entity validation in this particular case, bearing in mind that this could be dangerous, you can simply disable validation on your context before saving.

```
db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, is there a way to alter entity's behavior to not check for validation in this particular section?

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099949/entity-framework-mvc3-temporarily-disable-validation

Comment: Thanks a ton, adding `db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;` before saving the changes worked perfectly. Add this to your answer and I'll accept it. The reason I can't update the existing db info is because it is a yes or no answer agreeing to terms it should have been required from the start. Thanks!