# Edit User Data with savechanges modelstate.Isvaild problem

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, backend

I want to update user details like `Firstname`, `Lastname` and `date-of-birth`. although the `ModelState` is valid and `SaveChanges` doesn't work. I got some errors for `ModelState` which are about password and email fields.
the error about `SaveChanges` is about `confirmpassword` partial class I think that's what errors say!

Error = **The function evaluation requires all threads to run**.
**{"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."}**

here are my files
[database UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAe2D.png)
[database table user with datatype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXU6q.png)

**Registration and password usage**

```
        public ActionResult Registration([Bind(Exclude = "IsEmailVerified,ActivationCode")] User user)
        {
            bool Status = false;
            string message = "";
            //
            // Model Validation 
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                #region //Email is already Exist 

                var isExist = IsEmailExist(user.EmailID);
                if (isExist)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("EmailExist", "ایمیل شما قبلا ثبت شده است");
                    return View(user);
                }
                #endregion

                #region Generate Activation Code 
                user.ActivationCode = Guid.NewGuid();
                #endregion

                #region  Password Hashing 
                user.Password = Crypto.Hash(user.Password);
                user.Confirmpassword = Crypto.Hash(user.Confirmpassword); //
                #endregion
                user.IsEmailVerified = false;

                #region Save to Database
                using (sitedatabaseEntities1 dc = new sitedatabaseEntities1())
                {
                    dc.Users.Add(user);
                    dc.SaveChanges();

                    //Send Email to User
                    SendVerificationLinkEmail(user.EmailID, user.ActivationCode.ToString());
                    message = "تبریک ثبت نام شما با موفقیت انجام شد. " +
                        " و کد فعال سازی برای شما ارسال گردید به ایمیل:" + user.EmailID;
                    Status = true;
                }
                #endregion
            }
            else
            {
                message = "درخواست نادرست";
            }

            ViewBag.Message = message;
            ViewBag.Status = Status;
            return View(user);
        }
```

**profile view()** **usercontroller.cs**

```
            public ActionResult profile()
        {
            using (sitedatabaseEntities1 db = new sitedatabaseEntities1())
            {
                int userid = int.Parse(Request.Cookies["userid"].Value);
                return View(db.Users.Where(x => x.UserID == userid).FirstOrDefault());
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult profile([Bind(Include = "UserID,FirstName,LastName,DateOfBirth")] User user)
        {
            var message = "";
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        var account = db.Users.Where(a => a.UserID == user.UserID).FirstOrDefault();
                        account.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                        account.LastName = user.LastName;
                        account.DateOfBirth = user.DateOfBirth;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        message = "اطلاعات با موفیت ویرایش شد.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message = "مشکلی در فرایند ویرایش اطلاعات ایجاد شده است.";
                    }
                }
            ViewBag.Message = message;
            return View();
        }
```

**profile.cshtml**

```
@model projectwebsite.Models.User

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
                                {
                                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserID)
                                    <small class="text-muted">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)</small>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "form-text text-danger" })
                                    <hr>
                                    <small class="text-muted">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)</small>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "form-text text-danger" })
                                    <hr>
                                    <small class="text-muted">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)</small>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "form-text text-danger" })
                                    <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success"> submit</button>
                                    if (ViewBag.Message != null)
                                    {
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                            <strong>error</strong>@ViewBag.Message
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                }
```

**and last file user.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace projectwebsite.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))]
    public partial class User
    {
        public string Confirmpassword { get; set; }
    }
    public class UserMetadata
    {
        [Display(Name="نام")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "نام خود را وارد کنید.")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="نام خانوادگی")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage ="نام خانوادگی را وارد کنید.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="ایمیل")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage ="ایمیل خود را وارد کنید")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string EmailID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "تاریخ تولد")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "پسورد")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings =false, ErrorMessage ="پسورد را وارد کنید.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [MinLength(6,ErrorMessage ="6 حرف کمترین طول پسورد میباشد.")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="تکرار پسورد")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("Password",ErrorMessage ="رمز عبور برابر نیست.")]
        public string Confirmpassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: please share your inputs and the errors you got

Comment: The errors are **critical**. If you aren't going to provide them then we can't help you.

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing with the Models.. You are calling to use User as the model and the only thing in User is Confirm Password. Unless you have some other model your not showing. I am having a hard time thinking this code would work at all. I would also give the Action a name like Edit or ProfileEdit. You will only start to confuse yourself by using erroneous names.

Comment: @Soban-Re there is system validation error on savechanges(); and when i set error message for it,that show me user.cs file as you can see in post the last string confirmpassword {get:set} errormessage in the breakpoint also i need to remove password and emailid from modelstate to make modelstate valid i added user database and password usage in post thanks you can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer here: [Entity Framework/MVC3: temporarily disable validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099949/entity-framework-mvc3-temporarily-disable-validation)

By temporarily disabling validation I can bypass other properties validation check.